# Use Gmail API to read, send emails from web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, gmail-api

I wanna use Gmail API in my c# web forms application in visual studio 2015. All I find on internet is in MVC and I have no idea about it. Searching since few days but couldn't find anything simple. I can make project on google console but have no idea how to integrate it with my application. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!!.

Answer (score 1):

there is actually no difference between MVC and WebForm when you are trying to invoke some GMail API

google provides a Gmail API SDK for C#, you can reference it then your work will be much easier

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet

hope this can help you

Comment: thanks for your help. Its a console application dont know how i can use this. Can you plz explain a bit. sorry i am new

Comment: it’s the same in console and webform, what is your exact scenario

Comment: Right now i am creating project in google console should i select Application Type: Other or web application as for web application i need origin and redirect uris. I just want a new page in my application where i can access my inbox

Comment: then that is it, follow the steps, use the api sdk to query the messages and bind it to you gridview or wahtever, just like accessing the database